# split code file into more files

Tags: javascript, split, coding-style

I have a code file contains to many lines and I believe that all of these codes are not completely relevant together and can be apart to more files to make it more readable
can anybody give me an editor or online code breaker which can organize my code to make it apart?

thanks in advance

Comment: Node.js or browser?

Comment: I'm using my code in browser but I have node in my system if needed

Comment: Then the answer below is correct. You have to use webpack or browserify. These tools add a require function to your app, so that you can split your code on multiple files and require them using: `const moduleA = require('./module_a.js')`

Comment: excuse me there is a miss understand I don't want to pack my codes after I manually split them.
I have a bad and too long file which I want to automatically split it.
I want an app which can understand what parts of my file are not relevant to other parts and helps me to cut those lines and take them in a separate file

Answer (score 0):

Try to use webpack. This will require manually splitting code but will pay off.